# UINavigationController issue with popToRootViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, poptoviewcontroller

So lets say that I am in viewcontroller, C and I want to transition to viewcontroller D (which  is voteView here). So here's what I did:

```
VoteViewController * voteView = [[VoteViewController alloc] init];
        voteView.voteInfo = [array objectAtIndex:0];

    NSArray * viewControllers = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
    if ([[viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[ListViewController class]]){
        NSLog(@"LIST VIEW");
    } else if ([[viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[SpotListingViewController class]]){
        NSLog(@"SPOT LISTING");
    }

    [self.navigationController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[viewControllers objectAtIndex:0], [viewControllers objectAtIndex:1], voteView, nil]];
    [voteView release];
```

Running the code above, it prints LIST VIEW, which means that the RootViewController is a ListViewController. Now theoritically at VoteViewController when I do as below:

```
 if ([[viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[ListViewController class]]){
            NSLog(@"LIST VIEW");
```

it should print LIST VIEW, however it doesn't. Why is this? I also checked the count of the view controller and it's only 2. Why is it different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your ask is to transition to View Controller D (or `voteView`), you should be doing-

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:voteView animated:YES];
```

Related to your question, when you call `setViewControllers:` and access object at index 1, have you ensured that the array has two objects? In which method of `voteView` did you put the `NSLog`?